# Sequential delegate callback queue

Tags: ios, delegates

I have got an API I can’t impact on. API has a lot of methods with delegate callbacks like `-getInfo`, `-apiDidGetInfo:` . There are some limitations, you can only call these methods sequentially and delegate callback might not be called after request. Two methods never should be called at once. I want to convert this API to something like `-getInfoWithCompletion:` and use some kind of queue inside + some type of watchdog timer to finish current stalled task. How would you do that?

Comment: In your method you call the first API function and in the completion handler for that function you call the second function. In the completion handler for the second function you call the completion handler that was supplied to the method. You might also like to look at PromiseKit

Comment: @Paulw11 Order of calls is indeteminate. You should be able to call methods without explicitly queueing them in completion. Thak you for mentioning PromiseKit I will take a look at it.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. You can use a dispatch_group with a queue of operations and a dispatch_notify that sends the next operation

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, thank you I got it. I completly forgot to add one limitation. Please take a look.